# How to change FontSize in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am using `BottomNavigationBar` extension for displaying tabs bottom of the screen in `Xamarin forms` for Android platform.

Now I want to change FontSize of that table page Title on Small Screen Size device(i.e. Moto e). Other device(like Samsung Galaxy J7) display Title properly, but small size device truncate the page title. I  want to display title in two line if it does not fit in screen. 
How is it possible?[image: Look at this screen shot]

Thank you.

Comment: It seems you are using a non-standard Xamarin.Forms control. You need to check its documentation or source code.

Comment: Yes, this is a third party control.

Comment: Since it is third-party ,I'm afraid you can't reach it, you can raise new issue in github to describe your requirement.